# Is there a way to prevent the change of the selected row in a WPF DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I want to make sure that in a wpf DataGrid always the last row is selected (using MVVM). The code below is bound to a button. It selects the last row in the DataGrid. It works perfectly.

```
    private void SelectLastRow(object obj)
    {
        var temp = DisplayedRows.Last();
        selectedRow = temp;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedRow));
    }
```

If I put the same code to the SelectedRow setter (which is bound to the SelectedRow property of the DataGrid) it does not work. The setter is executed but on the GUI not the last row is selected but the one I have clicked. Any idea why? My overall aim is to prevent row change if there is validation error in the DataGrid.

```
    private object selectedRow;
    public object SelectedRow
    {
        get => selectedRow;
        set
        {
            var temp = DisplayedRows.Last();
            selectedRow = temp;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedRow));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Tronald and others helped. My aim was to block changing the row if there is validation error. I used `IDataErrorInfo`. In the code behind the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event checks if I want to select an other row. If it is true then I has to check if there is error in the dataGrid. `Validation.GetHasError(parent)` is not enough because it only checks the datGrid but not the DataGridRow-s. I press enter at the end of row editing.

```
private void DataGrid_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedItemNext = (e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement).DataContext;
    var selectedItemNow = dataGrid.SelectedItem;
    if (selectedItemNext != selectedItemNow)
        if (!IsValid(sender as DependencyObject))
            e.Handled = true;
}    

public bool IsValid(DependencyObject parent)
{
    if (Validation.GetHasError(parent))
        return false;
    for (int i = 0; i != VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); ++i)
        if (!IsValid(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i)))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is a bit finnicky due to the order in which events fire. When you click your `DataGrid` the following events occur in the listed order.

1. `PreviewMouseDown`
2. `SelectionChanged`
3. `MouseLeftButtonUp`

There are other mouse event occurring as well, but we'll just touch on these. Your `DataGrid.SelectionChanged` event is going to fire and update your `SelectedRow` property in your ViewModel (as you have seen), but because the `MouseLeftButtonUp` handler comes next, it will override your selected row binding you have created.

```
private void DataGrid_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   e.Handled = true;
}
```

But this will actually block all mouse events from firing in the DataGrid though (including the `SelectionChanged` event), which you may not want.

Since your goal is to override selection of certain items, you should consider binding to the `DataGridRow.IsEnabled` property instead. This way, it can be set as `false` in your ViewModel to disable row selection on validation errors should you choose.

Example

```
<DataGrid>
     <DataGrid.RowStyle>
           <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
               <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding MyIsEnabledProperty}"/>
           </Style>
     </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Dear @Tronald     Thank you very much. Now I see what is the problem. I set `e.Handled = true;` in dataGrid_SelectionChanged event. In this way the SelectedRow setter run in the VM. Then dataGrid_SelectionChanged run but still the selection changed. Do you know where is the problem? (My final aim is to prevent changing the selection if the row contains validation error.)

Comment: @IstvanHeckl I've edited the answer to meet better meet your goal